# Least number of repititions to get input numbers with given function

Tags: python, function, loops, combinations

I'm doing the Google foo.bar challenge and I made this python code to answer it. The problem is when the input number goes over about 16 digits the answer always returns impossible. This seems clear to me that this is incorrect because as I'm testing numbers I found a repetition in some of the input numbers and number of repetitions where adding another digit will always return another place value digit.

For example:
input of 3 and 94 will return 33
input of 3 and 994 will return 333
input of 3 and 99999999994 will return 33333333333
input of 3 and 99999999999999994 will return "impossible"

I don't understand why anything over a certain number of places will return "impossible" in my code.

This code takes as an input two random numbers up to size 10^50 as strings, represented as M and F. With these number you have to find the least number of cycles it takes to reach both of the numbers. Each cycle performs either a F function or a M function. A F function is equal to currentFnum + currentMnum and a M function is equal to currentMnum + currentFnum.

For example if you had 3 M and 2 F you could either get 5 M and 2 F or 3 M and 5 F.

```
def answer(M, F):

    count = 0
    currentM = int(M)
    currentF = int(F)
    listCycleType = []

    def getGreater(currentF, currentM):
        if currentM > currentF:
            greater = [currentM, "M"]
            return greater
        elif currentM == currentF:
            greater = [currentM, "M"]
            return greater
        else:
            greater = [currentF, "F"]
            return greater

    def getLesser(currentF, currentM):
        if currentM < currentF:
            lesser = [currentM, "M"]
            return lesser
        elif currentM == currentF:
            lesser = [currentM, "M"]
            return lesser
        else:
            lesser = [currentF, "F"]
            return lesser

    greater = getGreater(currentF, currentM)
    lesser = getLesser(currentF, currentM)


    for x in range(1000000):
        greater = getGreater(currentF, currentM)
        lesser = getLesser(currentF, currentM)

        if currentF > 1 and currentM > 1 and currentF == currentM:
            return "impossible"


        if currentM < 1 or currentF < 1:
            return "impossible"


        if currentM == 1:
            count = count + currentF - 1
            return str(count)
        elif currentF == 1:
            count = count + currentM - 1
            return str(count)


        yes = float(greater[0]) / lesser[0]
        if not yes.is_integer():
            yes = greater[0] / lesser[0]
            count = count + yes
            if greater[1] == "M":
                currentM = currentM - yes * currentF
                continue
            else:
                currentF = currentF - yes * currentM
                continue


        if greater[1] == "M":
            currentM = currentM - currentF
            count = count + 1
        elif greater[1] == "F":
            currentF = currentF - currentM
            count = count + 1
        else:
            currentM = currentM - currentF
            count = count + 1


        if currentM == 1 and currentF == 1:
            return str(count)

    return "impossible"


print answer("3", "99999999999999994")
```

Comment: Why can't you debug it? Follow the execution of the code. Step one is to change the `return` statements so you can see which `"impossible"` is being returned.

Comment: I just checked and it fails at the last return statement. Meaning the code looped through 1000000 times and didn't find the solution. I've tried increasing the number of loops but nothing works. I don't think it should be looping even near that many times anyway.

Comment: It seems obvious that putting a random large number in your code and hoping it works is not a good idea and will break at some point. We can't say anything more than that at the moment because you didn't actually describe what your code is supposed to do in your question.

Comment: update: I think it has something to do with the float and the length of digits that a float can be or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you change 
if not yes.is_integer(): 
To
 if greater[0] % lesser[0] != 0:
 Then it works perfectly.